# SQL Server Express Edition feature and upgrade concerns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-express

I want to install and learn T-SQL with SQL Server. The lightest edition that I can find is the Express Edition 2017.

1. Will the express edition support procedures, triggers, dynamic sql, PIVOT, sequences, dynamic management views and functions?
2. Will it be upgradable to adding ssis, ssrs and ssas in future (I read documentation on Microsoft community blogs, but couldn't find an answer specific to this edition), maybe I will need them in future.

Answer (score 6):

You should simply download and use [SQL Server 2017 developer edition](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/12/22/download-install-sql-server-2017-developer-edition-free/). Dev edition is same as enterprise edition so regarding feature you would not have any limitation and free to use for testing and learning. Do not use it in production

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.I did read about it,the main reason why I go after light weght edition is that my PC has very less RAM and HDD space.

Comment: Can you let me know how much space and RAM you have. Plus if you really want to learn SQL Server I believe at least 4 GB RAM plus fair amount of disk space would help you.

Comment: 4GB RAM,240 GB SSD

Comment: Sufficient for you to use DEV edition.

Comment: Agree with @Shanky. It may not run quickly, but it will run. (You may have memory issues, depending on what else is running on your laptop.)

Comment: @aravindnk You can constrain developer edition to the same 1GB of max memory that Express is limited to. You could also add/replace your RAM pretty cheaply - I don’t know what exactly you expect to do on a machine with only 4GB today.

Comment: Thank you all, I have installed DEV edition with SSMS .Works good.@AaronBertrand I definitely plan to upgrade soon,4GB is what came by default.

Answer (score 1):

The smallest SQL Server you can install for development purposes is [SQL Server Express LocalDb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15)

> Microsoft SQL Server Express LocalDB is a feature of SQL Server
>   Express targeted to developers. It is available on SQL Server Express
>   with Advanced Services.
>
> LocalDB installation copies a minimal set of files necessary to start
>   the SQL Server Database Engine. Once LocalDB is installed, you can
>   initiate a connection using a special connection string. When
>   connecting, the necessary SQL Server infrastructure is automatically
>   created and started, enabling the application to use the database
>   without complex configuration tasks. Developer Tools can provide
>   developers with a SQL Server Database Engine that lets them write and
>   test Transact-SQL code without having to manage a full server instance
>   of SQL Server.

Both LocalDB and the "regular" Express Edition have all the programmability features of Enterprise/Developer edition.  The regular Express Edition installs a Windows service and is running all the time unless you stop/start the service, and is about 500MB installed.  LocalDb runs only when your app is running, and is about 250MB on disk.